# Slow view building

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am in the process of converting an old asp.net forms application to MVC.  I have run into a snag where I am displaying results of a search.

I have an entity framework model of Classes, Class Details, Rosters and Class instructors.

[image: Entity Framework Model]

I have a search page where I wish to display all of the class details by class selected.

View:

```
@using System.Diagnostics
@model IEnumerable<SafetyReports.Models.DataModel.ClassDetails>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Class Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Location
            </th>
            <th>
                Region
            </th>
            <th>
                # of Attendees
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var c in Model)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(c.ClassDetailID);
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @c.ClassDate
                </td>
                <td>
                    @c.Location
                </td>
                <td>
                    @c.Region
                </td>
                <td>
                    @c.ClassRosters.Count
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Detail" onclick="alert(@c.ClassDetailID)"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public PartialViewResult SelectCourse(string id)
        {
            var e = new Entities();
            var i = e.ClassDetails.Where(x => x.ClassID.ToString() == id).ToList();
            return PartialView("_ClassesDetail", i);
        }
```

My problem is that it seem to take about 1 second per 2-3 classes.  I have one class type that has 1300 records and it takes about 5-6 minutes to return the view.  What am I doing wrong?  In the asp.net forms application I have a gridview that returns the same amount of data in seconds if that long.  It isnt using EF though, just a sqldatasource.  Could this be lazy loading?

Comment: i think this is the way you are generating the view (foreach...)  that takes time your EF query should not take that long.
 (anyway why are you using a string 'id' when ClassID is probably a int)

Comment: Thanks, the int seemed to speed it up quite considerably, though it's still taking about 30s to generate the partial view with ~1300 records.  Is there anything else i can be doing to speed up the view generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue, I had related objects being lazy loaded, I fixed the issue with including those objects with:

```
var i = e.ClassDetails.Where(x => x.ClassID == id).Include(x=>x.ClassInstructors).Include(x=>x.ClassRosters).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

firstly, as seen before using a int instead of a string for 'id' will speed up your EF query.

Here's one way to speed up the view rendering (or at least make it cleaner):

In view replace all the @foreach loop by a simple :

```
 //here Razor will automatically repeat you model displayTemplate for
 //each element of your IEnumerable 
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

And then define a Display Template for your model

~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ClassDetails.cshtml

```
@model SafetyReports.Models.DataModel.ClassDetails          
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Model.ClassDate
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.Location
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.Region
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.ClassRosters.Count
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Detail" onclick="alert(@Model.ClassDetailID)"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```